# upgrade ply package fails

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ply

I want to upgrade `ply` so I'm running -

```
pip install ply --upgrade
```

and I get the error (marked with **) -

```
Collecting ply
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/58/35da89ee790598a0700ea49b2a66594140f44dec458c07e8e3d4979137fc/ply-3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: ply
  Found existing installation: ply 3.8
**Cannot uninstall 'ply'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.**
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP Installation doesn't work (six, numpy and python-dateutil requirements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634510/pip-installation-doesnt-work-six-numpy-and-python-dateutil-requirements)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+It+is+a+distutils+installed+project